# how to insert multiple checkbox values(which is integer data type) in same row with foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, html

I know questions about multiple checkbox has been asked quite a few times but I am not able to workout with foreign key contraints. I have following 3 tables

```
table1: barber( bid int primary key, bname varchar(255))
table 2: services(sid int primary key, s_offered varchar(255))
table 3: appointments(bid int, sid int, app_time datetime, foreign key(bid) referecning barber(bid), foreign key(sid) references services(sid), primary key(bid, app_time))

 I have a form in which I have sid as multiple checkbox values and i want the values of these sid to be in same row in appointments
```

I have following code it seems to be working but only one value of check box gets stored in database.

HTML code:

```
<label for="assigned_barber"> Desired Barber:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name= "bname" id="rick"  value="rick"/>
            <label for="rick"> Rick</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="bname" id="dave" value="dave"/>
            <label for="dave"> Dave </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="bname" id="clarke" value="clarke"/>
            <label for="clarke"> Clarke</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="bname" id="anyone" value="others"/>
            <label for="anyone"> Doesn't matters</label><br><br>

        <label for="service_desired"> Service Desired: </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="s_offered[]" id="fade" value="1"/>
            <label for="fade"> Fade </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="s_offered[]" id="shave" value="2"/>
            <label for="shave"> Shave </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="s_offered[]" id="scissors" value="3"/>
            <label for="scissors"> Scissors </label><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="rest"/>
        </center>
```

and my php code is:

```
$bname=$_POST['bname'];
$s_offered = implode(';', $_POST['s_offered']);
mysqli_query($bd, "insert into appointment ( bid, sid, app_time) values ( (select bid from barbers where bname ='$bname'), '$s_offered', now())");
echo "the barber name is".""."$bname";
echo "service number is".""."$s_offered";
mysqli_close($bd);
```

but my main point is that how database mysql will handle this input? In my code I have used implode function which will separate the different inputs by ; (for eg. if user selects 2 checkboxes so in database table will it be 1;2 value stored) how will it be implemented because the field datatype in mysql is integer

Comment: but my main point is that how database mysql will handle this input? In my code I have used implode function which will separate the different inputs by ; (for eg. if user selects 2 checkboxes so in database table will it be 1;2 value stored) how will it be implemented because the field datatype in mysql is integer

Comment: So if I read this correctly, `sid` is an integer field?

Comment: //please try this code // foreach($_POST['s_offered'] as $value) {
 mysqli_query($bd, "insert into appointment (sid, app_time) values ( '$value', now())");
}

Comment: yes sid is integer field and foreign key referencing services table

Comment: @Arun: The code you have given me will work fine but it will store the values in multiple rows right? for eg. if user checks 3 checkboxes, then 3 rows will be inserted right? is there any way that all 3 checkbox values are stored in single row under sid column?

Comment: i think you are asking 3 checkbox values added in single row i.e (sid - 1,2,3) like this ?

Comment: you have to change the sid data type to varchar

Comment: yeah in a single row but my sid field is foreign key which is a integer data type.